# curl: (67) Authentication failure

Tags: curl

I am using Curl ming to transfer a file using a console application.
But I am getting the curl: (67) Authentication failure error.
The character has a '&' character in the password.
I can connect manually through filezilla and all, but the log file in the application shows this error.

Eg:
If `-u username:pass&word`  are the credentials,
console log shows this as

`-u username:pass    &     word`   as the credentials.

How do I eliminate this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Character `&` sends the command to the background. Having `&` in password it is actually making it `-u username:pass`. You can escape the `&` using a backslash (`\`).

```
-u username:pass\&word
```

Comment: Thank you, In my case, the escape character was ^